# AVIReader - taking too long to save frames

Tags: c#, .net, aforge

I am developing a program to grab images from four cameras and turn them into one picture only in style quad, 4 images in one. And it generate a .avi

```
        AVIReader reader = new AVIReader();
        List<byte[]> ImagemMainb = new List<byte[]>();
        reader.Open(_rootPath + Path.GetFileName(_arqsCam01[i]));
        while (reader.Position - reader.Start < reader.Length)
            {
                Bitmap aux = reader.GetNextFrame();
                Bitmap r = new Bitmap(aux.Width * 2, aux.Height * 2, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
                using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(r))
                {
                    g.DrawImage(aux, new Rectangle(0, 0, aux.Width, aux.Height));
                    ImagemMainb.Add(ImageToByte(r));                                                             
                 }                                    
            }
            reader.Close();
            reader.Dispose();
```

And here is the method ImageToByte

```
public static byte[] ImageToByte(Image img)
    {
        byte[] byteArray = new byte[0];
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            img.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
            stream.Close();

            byteArray = stream.ToArray();
        }
        return byteArray;
    }
```

Using these codes takes too long to finish the process!
When I have a list of 84000 bitmaps in that case are 280 videos with frame rate = 5, size = 320x240, it takes forever.
Would have any problem in this code or have a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the answer.

```
 AVIReader reader = new AVIReader();
 List<Bitmap> ImagemMain = new List<byte[]>();
 reader.Open(_rootPath + Path.GetFileName(_arqs[0]));
 while (reader.Position - reader.Start < reader.Length)
 {
        using (var aux = reader.GetNextFrame())
        {
             using (var r = new Bitmap(640, 480))
             {
                   using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(r))
                   {                                               
                       g.DrawImage(aux, new Rectangle(0, 0, aux.Width, aux.Height));                                                   
                       ImagemMain.Add((Bitmap)r.Clone());
                   }

             }
         }
  }
```

Every video uploaded AVIWriter I open the file .avi and add bitmap.
With this is much more fast and does not take up almost no memory.